# Single parameter with multiple values - referencing extended-choice parameter values

Tags: jenkins

I am stuck with the following situation in Jenkins.

A job needs to build multiple `make` targets. This will happen through multiple invocations of `make` per run as it allows only 1 target at a time. I want to allow users to select which targets to build with each run.

I tried with `extended-choice parameter` plugin (Multi-select), but could not figure out how to parse multiple values from it, and how to structure my call to `make`

Can someone help me with this

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: Sorry, the comment was not complete. So...If I assign 24 values to a parameter, can a user select the values he wants to build? And, will jenkins build them in order. I mean, ohh $TARGET has 4 values a,b,c and d. Ok, lets build a....done...lets build b...etc.. etc,..

Comment: I tried using "extended parameter plugin" wherein I could assign multiple values to a parameter. With the checkbox option selected, the user can select which values to select for this job. But, the job does not succeed. I defined the values as value=x,y..The failure result says TARGET=x,y not found

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extended-choice parameter will always list its selected values as `TARGET=value1,value2`. At best, you can enforce the values to be quoted like this `TARGET="value1,value2"`

You have to parse this `TARGET` value to get it into the format you want.

If you could pass targets to `make` in sequence, like `make value1 value2`, all you would need is to change that comma `,` in value of `TARGET` to a space . You didn't provide your OS, so I will assume *nix. You can use the following to quickly do that `${TARGET//,/ }`

Finally, since `make` does not appear to support multiple targets (according to OP), we need a loop.

So, in your Jenkins **Execute Shell** build step, type:

```
for currentTarget in ${TARGET//,/ }; do
    make $currentTarget
done
```

This will be equivalent to:

```
make value1
make value2
```

As for the order of thing: the order of these values will always be same as they are defined in job configuration. It doesn't matter in what order the user chooses these.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Use of "make value1 value2" returns the error:

Comment: It says you can specify only one target each time...So the build flow should be like...TARGETS=make1 make2....Perform the build with $TARGET=make1 and then perform the build with $TARGET=make2.

Comment: @Anvesh, modified the answer for your scenario: calling `make` for each target in a loop. Note that this is a very basic script with no error checking whatsoever. Also note an extra `/` in `${TARGET//,/ }` (to replace all occurrences of `,`, not just the first one.

Comment: I get the same error again. I am kinda new to this kind of job wherein a single Parameter has multiple values and user needs to select the Parameter values. First of all, is it possible that this kind of flow can exist...build $TARGET=make1..DONE...then $TARGET=make2 and so on untill all the checked values have been met...Is there any other way to get this thing going

Comment: @Anvesh You can't have the same error cause the new code does one target at a time. The modified code does exactly what you are asking: make target1, then make target2, and so on for each selected target value. Please paste the whole console log output of your failing jobs into the original post.

Comment: @Jninja, I can definitely try. Please edit the original question, and paste the job's console log, for both failing and successful builds. Or better yet start a new question, since your current question on `extended-choice` parameter is answered. Ping me with a link to the new question in a comment response below. Include `@Slav` so I get notified.

Comment: @Jninja, this is really difficult to read. Please make a new question on this subject. In that question, when editing text type tag `<pre>`, then copy your whole console log, then use tag `</pre>` after. To get full console log go to `http://<jenkinsip>/job/<jobnane>/<runnumber>/consoleText`. Please clearly indicate which one is working, which one is failing. Then copy a link to new question in here for me to see, and i will help in that new question.

Comment: @Slav Is that answer good also to my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455753/how-can-i-loop-thought-jenkins-extended-choice-parameter

Comment: @arielma The for loop solution should work for you too

Comment: @Slav You mean like that: 
```str = env.ENV.split(',')
   for (String values :str)
          sh "echo $values"```

Comment: @arielma I really don't know the jenkinsfile syntax, so can't comment, but if that syntax is correct, then yes

Answer (score -3):

REQUIREMENT:
The parameter $TARGETS had 26 values (Values might be added/deleted in future). The user is interested in selecting which parameters he wants to build this time.
$TARGETS=make1,make2,make3.......

TRIAL:
Jenkins "extended choice parameter". Could assign multiple values to a parameter and user gets the option to select multiple values.
During build with make $TARGETS, I got error, could not "make make1 make2".
I needed
make make1
make make2

SOLUTION:
In the build step, use "for loop"

for currentTarget in ${TARGET//,/ }; do
    make $currentTarget
done

Thanks to @Slav
Hope this helps people who might face similar situation.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you unaccepted my answer and then just repeated the same thing in your answer.

Comment: Oops..Sorry. I was trying to give the rating to your answer and I accidentally unchecked it. Reverted it back. Thanks

Comment: Cheers :), the reputation is like food for us. We work for food :P