# How can I loop thought Jenkins Extended Choice Parameter

Tags: loops, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have the below Extended Choice Parameter in my Job:

[image: Extended Choice Parameter]

In case I choose both values, how can I loop thought it in my `jenkinsfile`?

```
sh "docker run --rm --net=host -v ${WORKSPACE}:/app/ ${MyImage} --env ${ENV}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used (with the help of this post: [Single parameter with multiple values - referencing extended-choice parameter values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618693/single-parameter-with-multiple-values-referencing-extended-choice-parameter-va/22638509)):

```
str = env.ENV.split(',')
for (String values :str)
  sh "docker run --rm --net=host -v ${WORKSPACE}:/app/ ${MyImage} --env $values"
```